# Back slashes in xmapp on windows

Tags: php, windows

I instaled xampp on windows, with joomla 2.5 and require_once not works in directories because of this

"C:\xampp\htdocs\upconsole/administrator"

in this path slashes and back slashed are mixed.

Comment: Your question is....?

Comment: Do you want to replace the backslashes, or do you want to get rid of them at all. One solution could be using joomla functions to get the paths...

Comment: you can use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` on the slashes and backslashes so the interpreter itself will provide the directory separator depending on your OS

Comment: How can i solve this problem is there is a somethis in configuration of apache

Comment: I'm agree with `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` but it seems it looks like more at a good practice than having an impact on the code.

Comment: Can you post the code where require_once is failing?